# Why does sqlite throws a syntax error in the python program?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, syntax

My table is sqlite3 is created with the following:-

'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS gig_program ( gig_program_id VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY );'

When I try to insert data into the table using python 3.8 with the following:-

sql = 'INSERT INTO gig_program ( gig_program_id ) VALUES ( "20200524120727" );'

cur.execute(sql)

the following exception was thrown:-

near "gig_program": syntax error

When I cut and past the insert command to the sqlite3 console, it works.

I have also tried using another editor for the program (thinking that there may be hidden characters) but the result is the same.

I would appreciate help.  I have used similar methods in other parts of the program to insert data and they work without issue.

Comment: If you use sql = 'INSERT INTO gig_program ( gig_program_id ) VALUES ( \'20200524120727\' );' Does it work?

Comment: Your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for looking into my questions.

I found that it was actually my mistake.  The exception was actually for a second sql statement which I missed out the "FROM" word.

Thank you everyone for your time.

Hope everyone is doing well.